# How to restrict a Docker container to only access specific ports on the host and allow SSH traffic

Tags: linux, docker, security, iptables

I have a Docker container that needs to have access to certain ports on my host machine, but I want to restrict access to only those ports. Here's the command I use to run the container:

`docker run -it --network test -p 2020:22 --name my-container 229da73a2adb`

To restrict access to one of the host's ports, say 3030, I use the following iptables rules:

`iptables -A INPUT -i br-68c6feca2ecb -p tcp --dport 3030 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3030 -j DROP`

Additionally, I want to prevent any other traffic from being exchanged between the container and the host. I achieve this with the following rule:

`iptables -A INPUT -i br-68c6feca2ecb -j DROP`

However, I also want to allow the container to accept SSH traffic from the outside network but not allow any other traffic to be sent out from the container to the internet. Is there a way to achieve this?

How can I restrict the network traffic to only the desired ports?

I cannot use the --internal flag as I still need to publish ports.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer. With the following commands the traffic of all containers is closed and only ssh is played for them:

`iptables -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A DOCKER-USER -p tcp --sport ssh -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A DOCKER-USER -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP`